# Hibernate getCurrentSession() do i really need a transaction for a read-only type of query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, transactions, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to utilize Hibernate and am trying to avoid the management of session by utilizing the `getCurrentSession()`  which is provided by the API `SessionFactory`.  As I understand it, this will manage the session for me.  My problem is when trying to use it in place of `openSession()`, I am getting an error saying that I need to have an active transaction.  Online i have read conflicting answers, so i am still not sure.  I am trying to execute a read only query (basically a select), why do i need a transaction for that?

```
Error message: org.hibernate.HibernateException message: getNamedQuery is not valid without active transaction
```

More details:

Hibernate.cfg.xml - snippet

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="hibernateSessionFactory">
    <property name="connection.datasource">jdbc/DPARISC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
    <property    name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</property>
```

Nothing special in the way we create the SessionFactory

```
config.buildSessionFactory();
```

Now here is where the problem comes, on the createQuery

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getDB2SessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryStringBuilder.toString())
        .setParameter("orgId", request.getOrgId().intValue())
        .setParameter("busUnitId", request.getBusinessUnitId().intValue());
    query.setMaxResults(HibernateConstants.MAX_RESULTS);
```

Again the query is basically just a Select statement.  Do i need to have a begin transaction and then a commit even for things like this when i use `getCurrentSession()`?  Isnt that going to create a lot of overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers for your questions: yes and no.

Longer answers:

Hibernate requires you to have a session open when you perform anything. You can use `getCurrentSession()` only if you actually have opened one.

Why do you assume it creates a lot of overhead?

Comment: From the documentation though, i thought that getCurrentSession would either open a new session if one did not exist, or if it did it would re-use.  My question was more about the transaction side.  If you issue a query after using getCurrentSession, why do i need to wrap that in a transaction?

Comment: Because reading without transactions can lead to things like dirty reads and other problems.